# Conditionally sum a column based on a mod result

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT y.datamov,
       y.n_conta,
       y.sinal,
       y.valor,
       y.qtde,
       a.nome,
       '',
       0,
       a.lrdarc
FROM (
    SELECT k.datamov,
        k.n_conta,
        k.sinal,
        k.qtde,
        sum(k.total) AS valor
    FROM (
        SELECT DATE (b.dt_normal) AS datamov,
            b.historico,
            a.obs,
            a.total,
            a.qtde,
            b.sinal,
            c.nome,
            a.n_conta
        FROM caixa.rtitens a
        LEFT JOIN caixa.rtlan b ON (b.numero = a.n_lan)
        LEFT JOIN caixa.rtctares c ON (c.numero = a.n_conta)
        WHERE DATE (b.dt_normal) BETWEEN DATE ('2010-02-13') AND DATE ('2010-02-20')
            AND c.lrdarc != 0
            AND b.sinal = 'E'
        ORDER BY 1, 7, 5
        ) k
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
    ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
    ) y
LEFT JOIN caixa.rtctares a ON (a.numero = y.n_conta)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Which returns results like these:
[image: Query results 1]

My problem is: I need to conditionally "merge" two rows into one when the mod of the a.lrdarc is equal to 1. If this condition is not filled (ie the mod is 0), then it should show the column without doing anything. I've been trying to do this for a while and until now I have no idea on how to solve this. What can I do?

EDIT: I want something like this:
[image: Query results 2]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'merge'?

Comment: Look at line 1 and 2 from the results. They have the same `n_conta` and the same `lrdarc` values. `datamov` is the same too, but I forgot to expand it. I want to sum the `valor` from both  rows and show them as one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the expected results too. Create some by hand, so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Take a look at the first post. Note that I've rearranged the columns order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my boss stated, all I had to do was edit the inner statements instead of trying to manipulate the results on the outer query. We managed to do what I needed with this:

```
SELECT  y.datamov, 
    y.n_conta,
    y.sinal,
    y.valor,
    a.nome,
    '',
    0,
    y.lrdarc,
    y.quantidade
FROM (
    SELECT k.datamov,
        k.n_conta,
        k.sinal,
        sum(k.qtde_valida) as quantidade,
        k.grupo as lrdarc,
        sum(k.total) AS valor
    FROM (
        SELECT DATE (b.dt_normal) AS datamov,
               b.historico,
               a.obs,
               a.total,
               b.sinal,
               c.nome,
               a.n_conta,
               c.lrdarc,
               case when mod(c.lrdarc, 2) !=0 then
                    a.qtde
               else
                    0
               end as qtde_valida,
               trunc(c.lrdarc / 10) as grupo
        FROM caixa.rtitens a
        LEFT JOIN caixa.rtlan b ON (b.numero = a.n_lan)
        LEFT JOIN caixa.rtctares c ON (c.numero = a.n_conta)
        WHERE DATE (b.dt_normal) BETWEEN DATE ('2010-02-13') AND DATE ('2010-02-20')
        AND c.lrdarc != 0 AND b.sinal = 'E'
        ORDER BY 1, 7, 5
        ) k
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 5
    ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
    ) y
LEFT JOIN caixa.rtctares a ON (a.numero = y.n_conta)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Note that the select from the most inner query, where we've added this:

```
...
c.lrdarc,
case when mod(c.lrdarc, 2) !=0 then
     a.qtde
else
     0
end as qtde_valida,
trunc(c.lrdarc / 10) as grupo
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: Just a tip for the future: it is much easier to understand queries if you use meaningful table aliases.  Also, when asking questions here it may make sense to translate the table names you mention into English.  Furthermore (I cannot be sure as I don't speak Portuguese) usually there is no sense in using abbreviations and/or acronyms for table and column names.  In PostgreSQL, you have 63 characters for naming your stuff, it is very rare when it is not enough.

Comment: What @dezso said. You can also remove the `ORDER BY 1, 7, 5` and the (first) `ORDER BY 1, 2, 3`. It's redundant to have `ORDER BY` in internal, derived tables or subqueries (unless there is a `LIMIT` clause.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I must add that I'm not the one that made the query, I needed to update it. That said, the column names were made by my boss, so I thought that it was better to leave them like that. The same applies to the `ORDER BY` clause. Next time I ask something, I'll make sure that I'll translate the columns into English, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a CASE expression, something like:

```
SELECT y.datamov,
       y.n_conta,
       y.sinal,
       y.valor,
       y.qtde,
       a.nome,
       '',
       0,
       a.lrdarc,
       CASE WHEN MOD(a.lrdarc,5)=1 THEN y.FirstMergeColumn || y.SecondMergeColumn
            ELSE a.lrdarc
       END
...
```

Without knowing more, hard to guess what you are wanting... you didn't tell us what columns you want merged, what you mean by "merge" (I assumed concatenate) or what the divisor of your MOD is (I assumed 5).